# TypeError: must be string or read-only character buffer, not list

Tags: python, database, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a DB and get a data.

But when I am trying to write into a file it gives me the below error.

```
TypeError: must be string or read-only character buffer, not list
```

Below is my sample code.

```
import pyodbc
path= "M:/xyz/"
file_write=open( path +"files.test.log", "w")
#print "Connection started"
db=pyodbc.connect('DSN=DB_NAME;PWD=xyz')
#print "Connection done"
cursor = db.cursor()
book_value="WPZ.N"
query="SELECT book_id FROM Table_name WHERE book_value='"+book_value+"'"
#print query
cursor.execute(query)
book_id= cursor.fetchall()
file_write.write(book_id)
#str(file_write)
#print file_write
```

Please Guide on This.

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear which line produces the error, but I think it's `file_write.write(book_id)` that expects a string, but you give it a list of database rows. Loop through all rows of `book_id` instead.

Comment: try `type(book_id)`. see what it prints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns a list of rows, what you should do is to get the really 'book_id' with string type from this list and write it to the file.

Try this:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    file_write.write(row.book_id)  # not sure if row[0] works as well
    file_write.write('\n')  # new line or anything else you like
```

source: [pyodbc example](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor)

Answer (score 1):

```
book_id= cursor.fetchall() #List of rows

file_write.write(book_id) # you will get error `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

file_write.write(', '.join(book_id))
```

Comment: @Rohit check the solution.